# What do you use for profiling in Eclipse, now that TPTP is going to be archived?

Tags: eclipse, profiler, eclipse-tptp

Have you found a good alternative to TPTP, which is being [archived](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm), to profile Java applications in Eclipse?

I understand this is not exactly a programming question, so please just drop me a message if this is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

EDIT: There's also a relevant question, from 2008 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler) but I was looking for something a little more updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VisualVm, that comes with the JDK itself is good for some CPU and memory profiling, though, it doesn't integrate well with eclipse.

[YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) is a great profiling tool that integrates quite well with eclipse but its not free. You will need to buy a license for it.

[Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is another great tool that helps a lot in analyzing java heap dumps. It is perfect for pointing out any un-intentional memory leaks in a java application.

Comment: I liked MAT's analysis options, although it was a little difficult to get started.  Overall, found VisualVM a little easier to use, but that might just be me.

Comment: Adding a comment myself: there's an eclipse plugin to launch a java app *and* VisualVM [here](http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html)

Answer (score 3):

Its not part of the eclipse ecosystem, but I've used JConsole.  The current versions seem to work well.  I've thought about some of the commercial tools, but for me JConsole did everything I needed it to do once I read through its manual.

Comment: Thanks! It's however more of a monitoring tool than profiling right? I need to identify memory and cpu hoggers...

Comment: Yeah, actually I should have double checked, I meant VisualVM.  It has monitoring, but also both CPU and Memory use instrumentation, e.g. "profiling".  Unlike some of the fancier tools, you have to apply these instrumentation to a running JVM which can take several minutes (or longer), but I got usable results.

Answer (score 0):

I have used JProfiler for many years (more than 8 years) and this a great tool too, and the footprint is very small.

https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html

For me TPTP was on big project completely useless (it didn't work and crash)